# CoffeeScript - How to break a long destructuring assignment into multiple lines

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, coding-style

Given a javascript object in coffeescript form like this:

```
opts = 
  longProperty: 'value1'
  veryLongProperty: 'value2'
  veryVeryLongProperty: 'value3'
  veryVeryVeryLongProperty: 'value4'
```

A normal destructuring statement in coffeescript will be like this:

```
{ longProperty, veryLongProperty, veryVeryLongProperty, veryVeryVeryLongProperty } = opts
```

**Question**: is it possible to separate the assignment into multiple lines *in an elegant way*? <s>What's the most elegant way to do it?</s>

Comment: Hey @FrédéricHamidi, sorry I should have been asking what's the most elegant/conventional way to do it

Comment: Edited question so it is not subject to deletion (*primary-based question*).

Answer (score 2):

Answer is yes.

How about:

```
{ 
longProperty, 
veryLongProperty, 
veryVeryLongProperty, 
veryVeryVeryLongProperty 
} = opts
```

[Example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:opts%20%3D%20%0A%20%20longProperty%3A%20%27value1%27%0A%20%20veryLongProperty%3A%20%27value2%27%0A%20%20veryVeryLongProperty%3A%20%27value3%27%0A%20%20veryVeryVeryLongProperty%3A%20%27value4%27%0A%0A%7B%20%0AlongProperty%2C%20%0AveryLongProperty%2C%20%0AveryVeryLongProperty%2C%20%0AveryVeryVeryLongProperty%20%0A%7D%20%3D%20opts)

Comment: Thanks @apxp, but is this the cleanest way to do that?

Comment: What coulde be cleaner and simpler, like that answer? It is also readable.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would be to use shorter property names, and then deconstructing them in a single line.

```
opts = 
  shorter: 'value1'
  nicer: 'value2'
  faster: 'value3'
  better: 'value4'

{ shorter, nicer, faster, better } = opts
```

If that's impossible, you could try categorizing your properties into sub-objects:

```
opts = 
  subcat1:
    longProperty: 'value1'
    veryLongProperty: 'value2'
  subcat2:
    veryVeryLongProperty: 'value3'
    veryVeryVeryLongProperty: 'value4'

{ subcat1, subcat2 } = opts
console.log subcat1.longProperty

# or if you just need access to one property...

{ subcat1: {longProperty}, subcat2 } = opts
console.log longProperty
```

By putting your properties into categories, you might even be able to shorten their names.